# Potential Example of an algorithm failure

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, correctness-proof

I was looking an algorithm to solve a problem of finding whether and array contains a quadruple with sum = k,(k is input) mentioned at [GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-four-elements-that-sum-to-a-given-value-set-2/).
In one solution the approach mentioned is below,which i think i not correct:

1. Store all possible two elements pairs of array in some another auxiliary array and also store i,j indices of the elements.There will be $C(n,2)$ pairs.
2. Sort the auxiliary array.
3. Take two pointers,left=0 and right=n-1 to auxiliary array.

3.1. If auxiliary[left]+auxiliary[right]==k and there is no common index in elements represented by left and right, we return true.

3.2  else If auxiliary[left]+auxiliary[right]<k, we do left++

3.3  else we do right--

3.4 And this goes in continues loop until left < size and right>=0 or we get element at 3.1

Now my doubt is that in case sum of left and right elements=k and  there is some common element between left and right,then this algo will do right--.
I want to understand that why we do right-- here and no left++ and the other way.I think there must be some example where this scenario will make algorithm fail but i am not able to produce that.Can some tell that whether it will indeed fail or prove that it is always correct?

Comment: If I understood everything correctly, you are right. Geeksforgeeks has enough crap, so it's not surprising at all.

Comment: The continuation condition is not `left < right`. It is `left < size AND right>=0`, where `size = ` $\binom{n}{2}$. Note that this ensures that the pairs `(left,right)` run over all possible pairs of the auxiliary array. The case of `auxiliary[left]+auxiliary[right] == k` but with common indexes can be handled by doing `right--`, since eventually that invalidates the continuation condition. Observe that if there was actually a solution, it must have been considered before the continuation condition becomes invalid.

Comment: ahh...my  bad.i missed that part.sorry for left<right condition.i have updated the question properly.So in case there is something common, then i can do either right-- or left++ but not both,Is that correct?